# Open Software License Using library for separate project - Magento Varien

Tags: magento

I'm creating a `CMS` and I'd like to use the `Magento Varien` Library (its the base library for the Magento Application) in my codebase. I'm curious to understand my rights with it. Its using Open Software License ("OSL") v. 3.0.

1.) Am I allowed to use this library in my application if i include the magento license in the application. Just to be clear, im not using the magento application but merely the library Varien.

2.) Am I allowed to sell the `CMS` I am creating while using the magento varien library within it.

I believe my work is considered a `Derivative Work` but it might not because im not modifying the magento application but actually using one of there libraries in my codebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is based on my recollection of the therms and conditions -- I haven't recently read them so please feel free to inform yourself further and/or contradict me.

As a matter of principle GPL accepts **your work** which communicates with **their work** as non-derivative so long as your software works just as intended without **their work**. In this respect GPL requires you to also release **your work** in GPL if your code requires **their work** to function.

LGPL and OSL considers that **their work** is a common tool/library/framework which helps others build things meaning **your work** can require and rely on **their work** without you having to release **your code** as LGPL/OSL -- so long as you do not directly modify **their work** but merely use or interface with it as it was intended.

There might be a serious debate upon what using/interfacing represents.

For example if you have a C/C++/Java compiled object which has publicly available and documented entry-points (public packages, public classes, public methods etc.) then most likely these selected few entry-points are the fair-usage we're talking about.

In the case of PHP code there is no public/protected package nor any public/protected class system only public/protected methods meaning that you're prefectly capable of extending a class from **their work** but perhaps the original developer does not consider that to be a fair usage.

General rule of thumb: if **their code** is a library you can call any functions from that library; if **their work** has something like a plugin architecture and you're creating a plugin that's fair use too; if you're directly extending classes from **their code** or overriding them or editing them that may not be fair use (get written consent?).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Question though, am I capable of selling my software with respect to extending from their respective vendor library. The vendor library is OSL 3.0

Comment: Magento is using the OSL license specifically because it wants to be able to sell the Enterprise edition (which is just a bunch of extra modules doing hard-work for scaling purposes).

Comment: So the short answer is yes you can sell your work so long as the Varien lib is not altered within your distribution, and so long as you will always provide easy access to the Varien source code you used and offer the Varien part of your app with an OSL license.